# bash: replace string found inside curly brackets

Tags: bash, shell

please help., i am trying to find ways to delete the all numbers inside curly brackets except the first one from a file..

cat file:

```
option: {999}
apple: {111 222 333}
selenium: {097 083 083}
```

expect output file:

```
option: 999
apple: 111
selenium: 097
```

in the expected file, all the numbers found inside {} curly brackets are deleted expect the first number and also curly brackets have been removed.

i have already tried several options using sed, but they didn't work.

appreciate your help to resolve this issue. since i am new to bash/linux.

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Hi cycrus.. Thanks for info.. will follow your point from next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed

```
sed 's#[0-9][0-9][0-9]##2g' < input file |  tr -d '{}'
```

Demo :

```
$cat file.txt 
option: {999}
apple: {111 222 333}
selenium: {097 083 083}
$sed 's#[0-9][0-9][0-9]##2g' < file.txt |  tr -d '{}'
option: 999
apple: 111  
selenium: 097  
$
```

Explanation:

`[0-9][0-9][0-9]` <-- 3 Digits
`2g` <--  Means all occurence from 2nd occurenece of pattern
`tr -d '{}'` <-- Delete character and `{` or `}`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
sed -r 's/(.*)\{([^[:space:]]+).*\}/\1\2/g'
```

Comment: Nice. But why your expression `(.*)` is not greedy and selecting everything till the end